# Get Access Token for Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to access the Azure access token to get some information related to APIs hosted in Azure.

I used the code below in Visual studio and I get the token since I logged into VS with my credentials.

However, when I deployed this code I don't get the token and it throws an error, since the deployed environment does not have VS and just has the executable running there.

Sample code:

```
 AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", "tenantId").Result;
```

What is the best practice to get the azure access token?

Comment: When you say you deploy this code, what are you deploying it as - is it app service, or Function app, pls specify. Only if an authenticated context is present you would get access token for the resource that you pass to GetAccessTokenAsync function.

Comment: What I meant is, it is developed as a console application. while running the executable in a VM, it is giving an error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me

```
var tenantId = "<Your Tenant ID>";
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var token = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com", tenantId);
var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(token);
var azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(new AzureCredentials(
        tokenCredentials,
        tokenCredentials,
        tenantId,
        AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud))
    .WithDefaultSubscription();
```

Note : Make sure you install [Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime) for "TokenCredentials".

**REFERENCES:**
[Using AzureServiceTokenProvider to authenticate with the Azure Libraries for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-sdk-dotnet/issues/961)

Comment: The above logic works fine, If I use VS and I login to VS with my credentials.  When I logout of VS and give a try, I get this error.  Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. 
Exception for Visual Studio token provider Microsoft.Asal.TokenService.exe : TS003: Error, TS005: No accounts found.  Please go to Tools->Options->Azure Services Authentication, and add an account to be to authenticate to Azure services during development.  I don't want to add credentials because, If I run the executable on a diff machine, it will not work

Comment: Afaik we cannot get access tokens without authentication.